# Burninate [legacy]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

The tag wiki for [legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legacy) says:

> A legacy system is an old application, technology, mainframe, method,
>   etc. that may or may not remain in active use, while still having a
>   certain influence on an organization.

So it doesn't pertain to any particular software or hardware, but rather *anything* old.

Nobody can be an expert at *everything* that is old. Sure, I may be an expert at [xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode4), or another fairly outdated technology, but not all old technologies.

[legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legacy) has 18 followers and 462 questions, making it relatively unused.

Comment: It is a pretty useful contextual tag, selective to old guys like me that can remember the answer.  Such a question will surely appear in my personalized front page after filtering.  It does no harm, no point in destroying it.

Comment: @HansPassant I think I'm the old guy here.

Comment: Odd, I thought I was the Santa Claus in the [legacy] tag.

Comment: @HansPassant In that case, we need some better rules for when something is "legacy": MS likes to designate part of the C standard library that way, which kind of irritates me.