# 50 close votes are not enough for my moderation activities

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close

This is not me asking for [more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164684/close-votes-daily-limit-increase) than [40 close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171492/increase-close-votes-in-review) reviews [per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190492/would-raising-the-review-limit-help-with-the-close-votes-queue). Nor am I asking to [change the way close votes are handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders). These issue have been touched on time and time again. I'm here to present a problem, not a solution.

I've found myself moving more towards moderation in the last couple of months. I like going through the close, VLQ, edit, first post, etc. queues. And for the community to be successful, it is something that must be done ([and is being done](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)). Somebody has to go through and figure out which posts or actions are needed, and which are not.

But here's the issue:

[image: The Issue]

And you've [added a new Triage review queue, with more on the way, including a Help and Improvement queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage).

As it currently stands, 50 votes are simply not enough to use the functions of the site. Here is the math:

- Close Vote Queue - 35 votes, assuming ~5 will be audits/Leave Open
- First Post Queue - 10 votes, assuming ~10 will be answers/good first posts
- Low Quality Posts - 10 votes, assuming ~10 will be answers/audits/good posts
- Triage - 10 votes, assuming ~10 will be should be improved/looks OK

**So just from the queues currently in place, a solid 65 close votes are needed.** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033006/android-notification-bar-clear-getting-the-response-of-clear-button-in-android) is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032931/single-tap-should-show-some-text-in-eclipse-android) including [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031893/designing-multiple-screen-sizes-on-photoshop-for-android) posts [I just](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033019/how-to-create-class-based-view-that-is-both-createview-and-updateview) see [on the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033012/use-utf-8-in-url-codeigniter-seo) front [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033013/api-specifics-help-needed) that certainly should be closed. THEN there are the [countless](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267659/burninate-space) burninate [requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283129/burninate-numbers) on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267226/burninate-legacy) which I try to participate in. I can still edit the questions, but often many of them need to be closed, and that is part of what is done when tags are burninated, as [this post points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/4015623) - posts are improved/closed where needed.

In effect, **I'm just not able to use many of the tools that you provide me with to moderate the site**. At best, I can get through the VLQ queue and the Close Vote queue. After that, I can't do anything about posts I see on the main page, I can't participate in meta clean ups like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/282937/4015623), and I can't do the other reviews.

There are a couple of possible solutions to this:

- Allow me to flag question when my close votes are used up.
- Don't count close votes used in the review queues.
- Scale votes by reputation
- Simply add more votes

But whether they would be possible or not, I think that the issue needs to be addressed on way of another. As it stands, 50 votes aren't enough with the current system.

Comment: What happens when you reach 10,000 rep though? I'm curious - do the limits expand

Comment: @Coffee: No, theyd don't. You just get more flags, other tools and delete-votes.

Comment: Alex .Hmm, there is an argument to be made for "Ok time to go outside and breathe fresh air" . . Though I'm sure the mods here love help, we don't want you to take an unfair share of work. How much time does it take to exhaust your current "mod-powers" ? If it's less than 20 minutes I'd say "Hmm Ok that's a problem" , but - if more than an hour.. .see aforementioned point

Comment: @Coffee about 30 minutes at present...and it isn't done in a sitting. It's just between doing other work.

Comment: I re-iterate here what I said in the [SO Close Voters room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21047651#21047651): The problem is not the number of votes per person, it is the number of people that use their votes.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is based on the assumption that every user should be going through every queue and using all of their possible actions in every single one, every day.

That's just not the intended design here.  The typical case is people only using one or a few of the queues, rather than regularly maxing out every single one.

If you've run out of votes, it's a sign that you've done enough closing for the day.  Find something else to spend your time on until the next day, or find other moderation activities besides using /review to work on.

Comment: But suppose we have a user who just loves to help. Why would Stack prevent them? I do get that they need to take a break... but ... *it's free labor!!!* - it's like "Hi Stack, I want to increase your profit. Is it Ok?.... NO!???"

Comment: That's fair. But in practice, it ends up being 2 queues, taking about 30 minutes, that use up all the votes.

Comment: @AlexK You can blow through all your votes in 30 minutes?  IDK but that seems a bit fast to me, especially if you are actually reviewing the post.

Comment: @bluefeet typically, I "blow through" 40 close reviews in 5-10 minutes. Be my guest, [review my reviews, this stuff is publicly visible](http://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

Comment: @Coffee If you still want to help out there are plenty of things you can be doing, they just won't necessarily involve using /review.  Go answer some questions, go edit some posts that need editing, work on some re-tagging efforts, etc.  There's more to moderating than just /review.  Review is just an entry point into site moderation.

Comment: @bluefeet 30 minutes is a pretty fair pace for 40 reviews. If you use filters and hit the Skip button a lot, you can burn through them a lot faster.

Comment: This. FWIW, my philosophy for /review is based on the half-hour to an hour a day I used to spend in /tools, back when that was the only user-moderator UI: I'd check it every day right before the UTC rollover, and use up whatever close votes I had remaining after browsing the site all day, then burn delete/undelete votes until the time was up. The notion that folks should be doing this *all day long* is kinda crazy - looking at the worst posts on the site for too long is depressing.